# How to code Open, Read and Write on Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin

How to open files on Xamarin Android?

Can I do something like OpenFileDialog( ) ? I want to allow the users to look at files on their device and open them. Also to save them.

Like I normally do:

```
      OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog(); 
      openFileDialog1.Title = "File Open";

      try

      {

           if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {
```

etc.

Thanks.

RON

Xamarin

Comment: you can read/write using standard .NET `System.File` classes.  Xamarin Essentials has a [File Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android) you can use

Answer (score 1):

For xamarin android app, you can check [File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/).

A common requirement for Android apps is to manipulate files – saving pictures, downloading documents, or exporting data to share with other programs. Android (which is based on Linux) supports this by providing space for file storage. Android groups the filesystem into two different types of storage:

**Internal Storage** – this is a portion of the file system that can be accessed only by the application or the operating system.

**External Storage** – this is a partition for the storage of files that is accessible by all apps, the user, and possibly other devices. On some devices, external storage may be removable (such as an SD card).

And there is a sample about this, you can check it here: [LocalFiles](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/LocalFiles).

**Besides**, we highly recommend that you use [Xamarin.Essentials – File System Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) to achieve this.

> Xamarin.Essentials is a set of APIs for writing cross-platform
> compatible code. The [File System Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) is a class that contains
> a series of helpers to simplify locating the application's cache and
> data directories.

The following snippet provides an example of how to find the internal storage directory and the cache directory for an app:

```
// Get the path to a file on internal storage
var backingFile = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "count.txt");

// Get the path to a file in the cache directory
var cacheFile = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "count.txt");
```

**Note:**

You can also use [Xamarin.Essentials: File Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android) to pick a single or multiple files from your device.